# Does settings.json get synced in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I understand the "UI" version of my VSCode settings gets synced to my GitHub account, but when I manually customize the `settings.json` file do those changes get synced as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every change you make in the settings UI modifies (or adds/removes) a line in your `settings.json` file. Essentially it is this file that is synced to your GitHub account all the time.

To be sure, open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and run the `Settings Sync: Show Log` command:

[image: show log command]

The log shows every sync action.

Comment: sure, but what if I modify the settings file directly? You know? I only wonder because when making changes in the settings UI I get notified that the settings have been synced (in the top right corner). I don't get that message when editing manually - and I wouldn't expect to either.

Comment: It does not make a difference whether you edit the settings via the UI or via the file directly. Just to be sure you can check the sync log. I have updated my answer accordingly.